# PG Admin Sessions

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, session

I have a frontend written in MS Access that connects to a Postgres backend through ODBC. Sometimes the number of sessions reaches 100 and at that point I get an "ODBC call failed" error. I use PG Admin version 6.13 to administer the database. I noticed under Database activity -> sessions the following after some heavy usage on the database:

[image]

There are over 70 of these in the session tab, which causes the application to crash. If I close the application, the entries also disappear. Running the SQL returns nothing, as there is no data type with the name "lo" in the table pg_type. The table pg_type is a system table, not one that I created. Any ideas how to fix this excessive number of session entries? And what is this "lo" type?

Comment: Those sessions are initiated by Access, the ODBC driver or your application's code  - most likely your application does something which causes the driver to initiate new connections. "lo" is for [large object](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/largeobjects.html). I wouldn't be surprised if Access uses "large objects" for "BLOB" columns instead of `bytea` because it isn't really compatible with Postgres

Comment: The Access application has a connection leak. This has to be fixed in the application code.

Comment: I make sure to close all my recordsets after opening them, to avoid leak problems.
rs.close and Set rs = Nothing
When I don't need a recordset anymore

Comment: If you really did close all connections properly, the sessions wouldn't pile up on the server.

Answer (score 0):

That is showing the last query the session ran before it went idle.  That is an introspection query, where the app is trying to figure out what are the capabilities of the database it is connected to. Access probably does that automatically whenever a new session to PostgreSQL is opened. So your app is opening sessions, automatically doing its introspection queries, then never doing anything else with the connection.

"lo" is a type created when the "lo" extension is installed (which apparently you have not done--but there is no reason to think you need to do so, either).  The exact query probably has no significance, it just happens to be the last query on the list of introspection queries which get run.

Comment: The only extensions my database has listed are plpgsql and unaccent.
I went to the ODBC administration and unchecked "bytea as LO" which was checked. I haven't seen that session ever since. I will monitor the number of sessions in case something happens again